# Table cell td with max-width showing too much white space if line breaks

Tags: css, html-table

I am trying to make a table as small as possible. One cell may have more content then the desired width so I set "max-width". So in some cases the content will be broken into more lines, which is fine.
However, when a line breaks in two the table cell remains at the max-width, while it could be smaller if it would adjust to the now broken content.

Many words, easy to look at: http://jsfiddle.net/G3bcB/10/

```
<p>Too much white space:</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="leftcell">long texttext overflow</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p>Upper table could have same width:</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="leftcell">long texttext</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
</table>

table  { width: auto;  }
td { border: 1px solid black; }
td.leftcell { max-width: 100px; }
```

I am not sure if this is a feature of HTML, but to me it seems wrong.

Is it possible to make the field smaller (using standard css)?

Comment: Do you need to show all the text? The only way to get it into the td is to (1) make it smaller with clipping, font-size, etc, and (2) put a div in the td and overflow: hidden, whitespace: nowrap, etc.

Comment: The same problem is in FF, IE and Chrome.  If you stick a <br /> in there, the td is minimized.   I agree it seems wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this without Javascript. Fortunately it's not too complicated. I changed the class of the first cell to leftcell1 to distinguish it from the lower table and lengthened the string for demo purposes:

```
<td class="leftcell1">
    long texttext overflow long overflow
</td>
```

Here's the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G3bcB/21/).

And the javascript:

```
var el = $('.leftcell1');

//temporarily puts the text in the cell to measure it
function getWidth(el, txt) {
    el.html(txt);
    return el.css('width').replace('px', '');
}

//returns the string w/ the <br /> tags in the right place
function splitString(maxWidth) {
    var txtArr;
    var presentTxt = '';
    var futureTxt = '';
    var finalTxt = '';
    //split the words up if longer than the max width
    if (getWidth(el, el.html()) >= maxWidth) {
        txtArr = el.html().split(' ');
        //loop through the words and add them together
        for (var i in txtArr) {
            futureTxt += txtArr[i] + ' ';
            //check if the string is longer than the max width
            if (getWidth(el, futureTxt) > maxWidth) {
                //It is. Add it to the final string with a <br /> 
                //and chop off the trailing space
                finalTxt += presentTxt.substring(0, presentTxt.length - 1) + '<br />';
                futureTxt = presentTxt = txtArr[i] + ' ';
            } else {
                //it's not. Keep adding to it. 
                presentTxt = futureTxt;
            }
        }
    } else {
        finalTxt = el.html();
    }
    //if there is anything leftover in futureTxt add it to finalTxt
    if (futureTxt != '') {
        finalTxt += futureTxt;
    }
    return finalTxt;
}
el.html(splitString(100));
```